Is there a way to count members of a class?
I'm trying to write a function that would return the number of non-static members in a class. I need it for serialization library I'm working on. I need it to work with C++23.
I tried unsuccessfully several approaches. First approach would be using variadic structured bindings, but I don't see any compiler implementing it yet (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1hrzT9hMe). Is that in pipeline of any current compiler?
template<class T>
consteval auto count(T&& t)
{
    auto&& [...a] = t;
    return sizeof...(a);
}

I also tried a workaround using overloading on constraints, but all compiler issued hard error instead: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x7vcT8qhM
template<class T>
constexpr auto count(T&& t) requires requires
{
    [](T&& f){auto [a, b] = f;}(std::forward<T>(t));
}
{
    return 2;
}

template<class T>
constexpr auto count(T&& t) requires requires
{
    [](T&& f){auto [a, b, c] = f;}(std::forward<T>(t));
}
{
    return 3;
}

Is that a bug in compiler or error in code? Should c++23 compliant compiler fail constraints rather than failing with hard error?

You want reflection (it seems to me) - a feature that C++ does not have.

C++26 maybe if Vandervoodr's reflection makes it. For now, use boost.pfr to create  tied tuples out of aggregates.

@Red.Wave -- I'm not familiar with boost.pfr, could you give me a basic idea of the language feature used? I'm sure don't need to bring boost into my project.

Alternatively a simple C++ program can generate 100 specializations of a template for that.

@Red.Wave -- please elaborate, I don't understand what you mean.

@Gene it's best if you see the implementation of boost.pfr. You don't need to use boost. The basic idea is to declare a template and explicitly specialize it for 1 to 100 elements.

@Red.Wave -- I'm going through that, but I don't see a method that would allow them to count the members, I don't think they do. Perhaps I'm overlooking something.

@Gene I don't know boost.pfr either, but it appears to me that if I create a specialization for, say, 10 elements I kinda know how many I have, don't I? ;-) Also, iterating can simply be done "manually" (the code is ideally generated anyway).

@user4581301 Which part of the question needs details or clarity (even before unnecessarily copy/pasting godbolt code here)?

@Peter - Reinstate Monica specialization of what? I don't understand what specializations you have in mind.

@Gene if you have a tie of elements which is a tuple then getting the tuple_size is not a big deal.

@Red.Wave -- tuple is really a non-issue, how do you do it for a class? Once you know the number of members, everything becomes trivial. And I don't see boost/prf doing it either. Unfortunately I can't see the code without downloading the whole boost library, the links to code on their pages are broken.

Why do you want the count? Seems of limited value. I don't think you can do this from within C++ as it's introspection as Jesper mentioned (and AFAICT torturing C++ [and yourself ;-)]). However, you can do this with a utility/script you write that parses the file during the build. clang can do this: clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only -fno-color-diagnostics main.c > main.ast It's easy to parse this output and generate a .h file that has [whatever] you want. I do something similar when I want to generate a "serializer" function for a given struct.

@Craig Estey -- if you know the count, you can do structured bindings, and access any member by index, or just wrap it in tuple.

Okay. I tested this and it does work. I would have posted an answer with the code, sample input, and output but the question has been closed. Try the command I gave, look for RecordDecl and FieldDecl (nested).

@Craig Estey -- could you post the answer in Code Explorer as commented out code. My serialization library really needs this feature. It's really unfortunate that the question was closed.

main.c: struct A { int a; int b; double barge; }; struct B { int x; int y; struct A st; };and _redacted_main.ast: |-RecordDecl xxx <main.c:1:1, line:5:1> line:1:8 struct A definition | |-FieldDecl xxx <line:2:2, col:6> col:6 a 'int' | |-FieldDecl xxx <line:3:2, col:6> col:6 b 'int' | -FieldDecl xxx <line:4:2, col:9> col:9 barge 'double' -RecordDecl xxx <line:7:1, col:39> col:8 struct B definition |-FieldDecl xxx <col:12, col:16> col:16 x 'int'; |-FieldDecl xxx <col:19, col:23> col:23 y 'int'; -FieldDecl xxx <col:26, col:35> col:35 st 'struct A':'struct A';`

Here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/mhKdSCAg that may be easier to read

@Craig Estey - I see, thanks. It's not a trivial effort and I wouldn't be able to convince the users of my library that they need to preprocess their code before using it. I can probably do it for my personal project.

If you're trying to do serialization, you can generate the structs/code to do serialization directly from the AST output. I've done this for C in the past [which doesn't have "structured bindings"]. For each RecordDecl (a struct definition) create an array of field dump descriptors from the FieldDecl. Properly cleaned up in a [perl ;-)] script, adding this to the build can be clean and easy to use. Tell them it's metaprogramming and now you're one of the "cool" kids :-)

@Craig Estey -- that's how a small one month project turns into a two year long development

Yes, perhaps ;-) But, I already had the AST dump code in a script. It makes the parsing trivial as clang does the heavy lifting. Converting the AST output to a struct array would be easy. Give it a limited time trial. IIRC, I had the basic generation (using a custom parser) up in a day. Such a table is also useful for tracing/debug info to a log file, so, maybe the double duty is enough to convince you that the effort is worth it.

@CraigEstey that requires playing with the build/make file to create a custom build step. It's fun but requires doing it in a different language than C++. The final solution will hopefully be available in 2026, if Vandervoodr makes his reflection into the standard. In the meantime we have all the adhoc solutions. This kind of dark magic is normally rejected in code reviews. The common consensus is that if AST can handle it, then we need a way to reflect it.

@Red.Wave -- it turns out the solution (I don't mean reflection) is closer than I previously thought. Clang already has implementation in an experimental branch: https://godbolt.org/z/9hvWqrrr8

@Red.Wave That's two years out. It's adhoc only because nobody put in a github repo. Then, it's like any other such project. It's a one line addition to the build and a one line #include. (e.g.) If the project needs serialization, this can't be any worse that generating the dump tables by hand. In any case, Gene has to define the API for his serializer anyway (e.g.): dumpme(&mystruct,"mystruct",mystruct_dump_list);

magic_get (aka boost.pfr) is header only, and doesn't depends of boost.

@CraigEstey it's adhoc even if it's put in a repo. This is not the only implementation I've seen. Anything relying on external tools is generally not too wellcome; even the preprocessor is considered alian. Header-only black voodoo is not desirable. A direct solution is needed, but we can settle on header-only libraries for now. I found one header-only library that even extracted the names of data members of an aggregate.

@Red.Wave Anything relying on external tools is generally not too wellcome Sez who? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers As to magic_get, it's 7000 lines of code (of stunning complexity) to do what can be done in a fraction of that.

@CraigEstey believing or not, that's the trend in standardization. There's no limit on what can be done. But those solutions are outside the context of C++ as a language.

@Jarod42 -- thanks, I browsed through the code (can't say I studied it, so my conclusion can be incorrect). My conclusion, it's not doing what is needed. It's unnecessary complex probably because it targeted C++14. Basically what they do is creating a tuple from an aggregate, the rest is trivial if done in C++20. Now the basic problem is that they only support built-in types and pointers and enumerate them using is_same. That code can't deal with arbitrary user-defined types, I think it allows a user to register a user-defined type, but that defeats the whole purpose of this exercise.

It works as long as the type is aggregate initializable without base class. There are indeed extra complexity to also support C++14. IIRC, code is split and C++14 support can be drop. And indeed, once we have tuple, it become regular code :-)

How to get the number of members in a class at compile time

@user12002570 -- what does it have to do with this question?

There is a solution to this problem for aggregate types. It's based on the aggregate initialization, which allows as many initializers as there are non-static members of the class. To count the number of members, we increase the number of initializers until initialization fails. We can create a type that is convertible to any other type to be used as an initializer. This is similar to boost.pfr.
struct ignore_t { template<class T> constexpr operator T(){ return {};} };

constexpr auto count(auto&& t, auto&& ...ignore)
{
    using type = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>;
    static_assert(std::is_aggregate_v<type>);

    if constexpr(requires{ type{ignore...};})
        return count(t, ignore_t{}, ignore...);
    else
        return sizeof...(ignore) - 1;
}

struct A { int a; int b;};

int main()
{
    static_assert(count(A{}) == 2);
    static_assert(count(std::array<int, 100>{}) == 100);
}

The general case for non-aggregate types doesn't have a solution in C++23. Any attempt of using structured bindings in constraints ends with a hard error. The solution will be available when P1061 becomes the part of the Standard.

You can look at how it is done in boost::pfr. It only works for aggregates though (some sfinae trick around aggregate initialisation syntax).
In general case I doubt you can do better without a compiler plugin.
Depending on your use case you may find boost::hana ADAPT_* macros useful.

tnx, we discussed pfr in the comments above ☝️
clang P1061 branch has a working solution (https://godbolt.org/z/E1eYKjee3), but I don't think it will go to release until included in the next Standard.

An answer should not be based essentially on following a link. Please explain how boost::pfr does this.
